# Unable to convert geo_type::Polygon into geos::Polygon: could not find from_geo in geos

Tags: rust, geojson, geos

I have a geojson document on which I want to perform some GEOS transforms on, such as: calculating the intersection, subtracting a polygon from another etc.

I have been able to create a `geo_types::Polygon` from the document but haven't been able to convert that to a GEOS Polygon. The documentation for the geos library says that this is possible, but I am getting compilation errors.

```rust
use serde_json::{Result, Value};
use geo_geojson;
use geos::from_geo::TryInto;
use geos::{Error, Geometry};

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties" : {},
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [ [ [ -80.2006099057282, 25.7667778809006], [ -80.2005810927863, 25.7667893295156],
                [ -80.2005511360631, 25.7667981904308], [ -80.2005203313322, 25.7668043699427], [ -80.2004889842378, 25.7668078025078],
                [ -80.2004574067358, 25.766808451653], [ -80.2004259134638, 25.7668063104759], [ -80.2003948180789, 25.7668014017381],
                [ -80.2003644296081, 25.7667937775553], [ -80.2003350488499, 25.7667835186779], [ -80.2003069648777, 25.7667707333574],
                [ -80.2002804517018, 25.7667555557905], [ -80.2002557651654, 25.7667381441435], [ -80.2002331401646, 25.7667186781729],
                [ -80.2002127882898, 25.7666973564876], [ -80.200194895997, 25.7666743935394], [ -80.2001796233871, 25.7666500164743],
                [ -80.2001671036392, 25.7666244620256], [ -80.2001574430594, 25.7665979736533], [ -80.2001507216193, 25.7665707991263],
                [ -80.2001469937692, 25.7665431886774], [ -80.2001462892496, 25.766515393747], [ -80.2001486136429, 25.7664876661955],
                [ -80.200153948486, 25.7664602577369], [ -80.2001622509086, 25.7664334192908], [ -80.2001734529129, 25.7664073999664],
                [ -80.2001874605259, 25.7663824454984], [ -80.2002041531028, 25.7663587960835], [ -80.2002233830273, 25.7663366837049],
                [ -80.2002449759842, 25.7663163291135], [ -80.2002687318761, 25.7662979386737], [ -80.2002944263789, 25.7662817012691],
                [ -80.2003218130656, 25.7662677854259], [ -80.2003506260038, 25.7662563367582], [ -80.2003805827209, 25.7662474758012],
                [ -80.2004113874437, 25.7662412962597], [ -80.2004427345288, 25.766237863678], [ -80.2004743120208, 25.7662372145296],
                [ -80.200505805283, 25.7662393557171], [ -80.2005369006592, 25.7662442644785], [ -80.2005672891229, 25.7662518886976],
                [ -80.2005966698762, 25.7662621476228], [ -80.200624753846, 25.7662749330014], [ -80.2006512670223, 25.7662901106348],
                [ -80.2006759535611, 25.7663075223545], [ -80.2006985785666, 25.7663269884019], [ -80.200718930447, 25.7663483101652],
                [ -80.2007368227461, 25.7663712731897], [ -80.2007520953618, 25.7663956503261], [ -80.2007646151143, 25.7664212048378],
                 [ -80.2007742756976, 25.766447693262], [ -80.2007809971394, 25.7664748678266], [ -80.20078472499, 25.766502478297],
                  [ -80.2007854295097, 25.7665302732315], [ -80.2007831051166, 25.7665580007696], [ -80.2007777702746, 25.7665854091976],
                   [ -80.2007694678545, 25.7666122475983], [ -80.2007582658544, 25.7666382668644], [ -80.2007442582467, 25.7666632212646],
                   [ -80.2007275656759, 25.7666868706053], [ -80.2007083357575, 25.7667089829062], [ -80.2006867428059, 25.7667293374198],
                   [ -80.2006629869175, 25.7667477277848], [ -80.200637292416, 25.7667639651196], [ -80.2006099057282, 25.7667778809006]]]
            }
        }"#;

    // Parse the string of data into serde_json::Value.
    let serialized: Value = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    let collection: geo_types::GeometryCollection<f64> = geo_geojson::from_str(&serialized.to_string()).unwrap();
    for geom in collection {
        let poly = geom.into_polygon().unwrap();
        let converted_poly: geos::Geometry = (&poly).try_into().expect("failed conversion");
    }
}
```

I expect this to compile and have `converted_poly` be a `geos::Polygon`. Instead I get this from the compiler:

`could not find from_geo in geos`

`no method named try_into found for type &geo_types::polygon::Polygon<f64> in the current scope`

Both the `import` and the `try_into` call are referenced on the first page of [the documentation for the geos crate](https://docs.rs/crate/geos/5.0.0) under the "Conversion from rust-geo" section.

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Answer (score 1):

The `from_geo` module [is behind a feature flag](https://github.com/georust/geos/blob/37b2e0d456a2120d1a60c2e5f269570b2ee287dd/src/lib.rs#L65-L66):

```
#[cfg(any(feature = "geo", feature = "dox"))]
pub mod from_geo;
```

You need to specify that feature when you add the crate to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
geos = { version = "5.0.0", features = ["geo"] }
```

You should also file issues with the crate to document this.

See also:

- [Cargo documentation for feature flags](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section)

Comment: Thank you very much! This does indeed solve the issue! I am pretty new to Rust, so this was especially confusing.